# Accessing Object Properties when object is inside another object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am using javascript/ mongoose. I have the following mongoose/mongodb appeal object

```
{
  _id: 5b0f36266a4dcb1cb8feebd6,
  eventName: 'General Meeting',
  eventDate: 2018-12-22T00:00:00.000Z,
  eventType: 'DMs',
  reason: 'Emergency',
  reasonDescription: 'My dog passed away',
  submissionDate: '30/5/2018 @ 18:39:18',
  requester: {
    events: [5b079c109f2526395a2a8867, 5b0919a81d593006691d5c29, 5b0919c41d593006691d5c2a],
    wentEvents: [5b079bcb9f2526395a2a8865, 5b079bcb9f2526395a2a8865, 5b079bcb9f2526395a2a8865, 5b0919901d593006691d5c28, 5b0919901d593006691d5c28, 5b0919901d593006691d5c28, 5b0919901d593006691d5c28, 5b0919901d593006691d5c28, 5b0919901d593006691d5c28],
    programmingEvents: [5b079bcb9f2526395a2a8865, 5b079bcb9f2526395a2a8865, 5b079bcb9f2526395a2a8865],
    socialEvents: [],
    serviceEvents: [5b0919901d593006691d5c28, 5b0919901d593006691d5c28, 5b0919901d593006691d5c28, 5b0919901d593006691d5c28, 5b0919901d593006691d5c28, 5b0919901d593006691d5c28],
    appeals: [5b0bcd7c91ce990a289eba91, 5b0f34f3aab8a41c61fe347b, 5b0f36266a4dcb1cb8feebd6, 5b0f3be76787d51fc065a363, 5b0f3dcd7e60351feb17ca89],
    _id: 5b092f18ada6ba0f83cb8fdd,
    username: '666666666',
    major: 'French Studies',
    phoneNumber: '6823316625',
    subcommittee: 'SHIP',
    firstName: 'Jacob',
    lastName: 'Mullen',
    email: 'jacab.@gmail.com',
    birthday: '0022-02-22',
    meetingPoints: 2,
    role: 'member',
    __v: 26
  },
  __v: 0
}
```

I am trying to read the firstName property that is inside the requester property/object which is inside the appeal object. So `firstName < requester < appeal`. I have typed this: `name = appeal.requester.firstName` but I get the following error: `Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined`. Any ideas why?

Here is my Schema:

```
var AppealSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    eventName: String,
    eventDate: Date, 
    eventType: String,
    reason: String,
    reasonDescription: String,
    submissionDate: String,
    staffDecision:String,
    requester: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
});
```

NB: I HAVE POPULATED THE REQUESTER OBJECT

Comment: How and where are you displaying the object above? Could it be the `requester` property is not defined when you attempt to read `appeal.requester` but is added by the time you display the `appeal` object?

Comment: first that is not a valid js object (missing some quotes) and second nothing wrong with the way that you trying to get first name, the error indicates that appeal object doesn't have any property called requester, maybe you have typo?

Comment: Show you schema as it's likely different to what the document is. Please be careful tagging these questions as JavaScript, because it often "looks like" something else to those who don't understand mongoose.

Comment: I edited my comment but it's not valid js object either

Comment: When looking at this rather invalid JavaScript object, I can only see that the key `requester`, which holds another object, has a key `firstName`. However, the shown object above has no `firstName` key included in the `appeals`[!sic] property. This is due to the fact, that the `appeals` property holds an array of strings, which are some unpopulated ids from your mongo database. You have to populate all the ids which are located in the `appeals` array in order to get a `firstName` IF however the populated data holds such a property itself.

Comment: You're showing a referenced object in the schema. You either have not populated that object ( which would result in undefined ) or there is still a mismatch in the properties on the referenced schema you are showing. Where the latter is the case you either fix the schema or use `lean()` or `toObject()` to get the underlying document. If you simply have not called `populate()` then you probably just had the misconception the data was retrieved for you. Show the `User` schema if you think you actually called `populate()`, or better yet show the call where you are doing so.

Comment: I did populate the requester object. That's why the firstName is appearing